# How to conditionally pass a parameter to wordpress search to limit post types?

Tags: search, pre-get-posts

I have a site with a subsection containing a custom post type, "artwork"

I have an overall site search working how I'd like it to - it searches all of my posts and custom post types.  I would like to add a second search inside of my artwork subsection, that only searches the "artwork" custom post type.  I know I can limit my search results like this:

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type','artwork');
    };
    return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

But that affects the sitewide search too. How can I set the post type ONLY on certain instances of the search form?  I don't need a dropdown or any way for the user to choose, there are just certain pages where I'd like to include limited search instead of the overall site search.

Comment: How do you determine which instances the code should effect? I am not asking for the code, just the logic. Certain pages? Specific templates? What?

Comment: the single-artwork.php page and the archive-artwork.php page - my problem is that I'm not sure how to a conditional to a pre_get_posts filter based on where the query request is coming from (single-artwork.php), as opposed to the template it is affecting (search.php) - or if that's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "natural" artwork archive (typically setting `has_archive` to `true` in your `register_post_type()` arguments), you already have the functionality in place:

```
http://example.com/artwork/?s=query
```

...assuming `artwork` is your archive slug, WordPress will search only artwork for "query".

Just set the `action` attribute of the search form to the archive URL, like so:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'artwork' ) ?>">
```

Comment: Ah! Perfect - so simple I wasn't thinking along those lines at all. Thank you..!!

Comment: Upvote for lateral thinking!